# Nginx: I cannot get a 301 redirect from the Query Paramaeter to the Path

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect:

From:

```
http://www.fascinate.jp/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=en
```

To:

```
https://www.fascinate.jp/english/brand/devoa/
```

The following is the redirect settings for my current site:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_virtuemart&page=shop\.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=en($|&)

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://www.fascinate.jp/english/brand/devoa/? [L,R=301]
```

How should I rewrite the Apache Settings so I can use it with Nginx?

The version of Nginx I am using is `nginx/1.9.11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second rewrite condition translates directly to an `if` block. The actual rewrite translates to a `return 301` in its simplest form. Like this:

```
if ($args ~ "(^|&)option=com_virtuemart&page=shop\.browse&manufacturer_id=4&Itemid=62&limitstart=0&lang=en($|&)") {
    return 301 https://www.fascinate.jp/english/brand/devoa/;
}
```

`nginx` is not good at implementing multiple conditions. The `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80` will only cause problems if you serve both SSL and non-SSL from the same `server` block. If you can separate out non-SSL into its own server block, then the above `if` block can be applied only to the non-SSL URLs.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return) for more. And of course [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: I tried it soon after but the redirect did not work.
Is the location directive path fine as a "/" (slash)?

Comment: No. The URI will be processed by your `.php` location block.